# AutoMapper to map a nested list object

Tags: c#, automapper

I have 2 objects : Parent and ParentDTO :

```
class ParentDTO
    {
        public string AttA { get; set; }
        public List<List<BDto>> AttrBNestedList { get; set; }
    }
    class BDto
    {
        public string AttrC { get; set; }
        public int AtterD { get; set; }
        public string AtterE { get; set; }

        public CDto AttrFobj { get; set; }
    }

    class CDto
    {
        public string AttrG { get; set; }
        public int AtterH { get; set; }
    }

    //--------------------------------------
    class Parent 
    {
        public string AttA { get; set; }
        public List<B> AttrBList { get; set; }
    }
    class B
    {
        public string AttrC { get; set; }
        public int AtterD { get; set; }
        public string AtterE { get; set; }

        public C AttrFobj { get; set; }
        public C AttrGobj { get; set; }
        public C AttrHobj { get; set; }

    }

    class C
    {
        public string AttrI { get; set; }
        public string AttrJ { get; set; }
        public int AtterK { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to using AutoMapper to map data from ParentDto object to Parent object 
(all data in ParentDto has to transfer to Parent, but first element from AttrBNestedList  copy to AttrBList)

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CDto, C>();
Mapper.CreateMap<BDto, B>();
Mapper.CreateMap<ParentDto, Parent>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.AttrBList , opt => opt.AttrBNestedList.singleorDefault??);
```

I need just singleorDefault item from  `List<List<BDto>> AttrBNestedList` map to  `List<B> AttrBList`

Can anyone help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error which doesn't allow you to use `SingleOrDefault()`, you need to use `MapFrom` method:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ParentDTO, Parent>().ForMember(dest => dest.AttrBList, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.AttrBNestedList.SingleOrDefault()));
```